# Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List'<School.Models.Subject>' to 'School.Models.Subject

Tags: c#

I have a problem saving the Subjects list into a file. The Subject has an ID and Name only.
I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List'<School.Models.Subject>' to 'School.Models.Subject
```

Any idea how can I fix this? I appreciate your help!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using School.Models;
namespace School.Repositories
{
    public class SubjectsRepository
    {
        public SubjectsRepository()
        {
            Database = new List<Subject>();
            File.AppendAllLines("Subjects.txt", new List<Subject> { Database });
        }
        public List<Subject> Database { get; set; }



        // Create Subject
        public void Create(Subject newSubject)
        {
            Database.Add(newSubject);
        }

        // Delete Subject
        public void Delete(Subject chooseSubject)
        {
            Database.Remove(chooseSubject);
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qogSH.png)

Comment: Can you add the full CallStack?

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to initialize a new List although you can :

```
new List<Subject>(Database)
```

you can do something like this:

```
File.AppendAllLines("Subjects.txt", Database.Select(s => s.ID+" "+s.Name);
```

But for this code you will get an empty file

Comment: why did the file is not fulfilled with subjects?

Comment: because after you declared the Database list, you didn't add any subject

Comment: but when I run the app, I can created few subjects. they are still in the Database I can view them. What am I missing?

Comment: you are creating new Database list in the constructor and in the next line you are writing it to a file. So, no way there is items in the list in this line. You should move this line    File.AppendAllLines("Subjects.txt", Database.Select(s => s.ID+" "+s.Name); to somewhere else

Answer (score -1):

You cannot initialize a list with an existing list, only individual items (e.g.  `new List<Subject> { mySubject }`). You could _copy the list using the constriuctor (`new List<Subject>(mySubject)`), but not using initialization syntax (curly brackets).

That said, you don't *need* a new list of subjects. You want a list of strings to write to the file, not a list of subjects. You could do

```
File.AppendAllLines("Subjects.txt", Database.Select(s => s.ToString());
```

But that's only meaningful if `Subject` has a `ToString` override. Also `Database` is empty at this point so you'll get an empty file anyways.

Comment: Em... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__

Comment: @Charlieface That's creating a copy of a list using the constructor, not initialization syntax. I could have been clearer that using parentheses instead of brackets would work, but I think the rest of the answer is more important.